# Is there a mathematical term for "implied by an assertion"?

Tags: terminology

For example, given the assertion that $m, n \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, then $m + n \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. This is not something that was originally asserted, but it is a direct logical consequence of the original assertion. Is there a commonly used term for such a thing?

Comment: Uh... “implication,” “consequence.”

Comment: "If A, then B" is a [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) : A is the *antecedent* and B is the *consequent*.

Comment: Also, A is a *sufficient* condition for B.